# How to convert two strings to a list?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, serial-port

I'm doing some stuff with serial communication and when transmitting data, the buffer often get split up into parts.

I'm transmitting a list of 10 integers and I have a while loop to constantly read the serial data. It may look like this:

```
b''
b'x[-'
b'384,-368,-304,-96,0,-112,-352,256,304,640]'
b''
b''
b'None'
b'y[608,5'
b''
b'60,432,-1120,-1568,272,432,64,192,256]'
b''
b''
b'None'
```

The loop that produces this output is (`ser` is a `Serial` object):

```
while True:
    bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
    s = ser.read(bytesToRead)
    print(s)
```

The number of strings (I know they're bytes, but whatever) between the lists and whether it will be `b""` or `b"None"` is random.

So my question is how to produce two lists like:

```
[-384,-368,-304,-96,0,-112,-352,256,304,640]
[608,5,60,432,-1120,-1568,272,432,64,192,256]
```

from the example input above. I tried a bunch of things with nested `if`s and regular expressions, but it can't get it to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can save the data readed in a string object while you read it and when you detect a final of array, like `]` or `None` can process this string to extract your numbers, using `split` or another tools.

Like a first approach, or example, to start:

```
string = 'x[-384,-368,-304,-96,0,-112,-352,256,304,640]'
numbers = string.split(',')

numbers[0] = numbers[0][2:]
numbers[len(numbers)-1] = numbers[len(numbers)-1][:-1]

ns = [int(n) for n in numbers]
```

And you will have:
 `[-384, -368, -304, -96, 0, -112, -352, 256, 304, 640]`

Comment: That's useful and all, but it still doesn't answer my question. I know how to do it if the list is in a single line. What I'm trying to do is construct a list from **two** or more strings. The core of the problem is that the input is inconsistent, so things can fail at many points, What I'm trying to make is an algorithm that's robust against those inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall()` to find all integers:

```
import re
while True:
    bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
    s = ser.read(bytesToRead)
    lst = re.findall(r'\-?\d+', s)
    if lst:
        print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with bytes and not string, (different data types), I suggest to you the following code (similar to Kasramvd's solution with slight change):

```
list_of_integers = []
bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
while bytesToRead:
    s = ser.read(bytesToRead)
    lst = re.findall(b'\-?\d+', s)
    if lst:
        print('Captured: ' + lst)
        list_of_integers.extend(lst)        
    bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
```

Test:

```
>>> list_of_integers = []
>>> s1 = b'384,-368,-304,-96,0,-112,-352,256,304,640]'
>>> lst = re.findall(b'\-?\d+', s1)
>>> if lst:
        list_of_integers.extend(lst)    


>>> list_of_integers
[b'384', b'-368', b'-304', b'-96', b'0', b'-112', b'-352', b'256', b'304', b'640']
>>> s2 = b'60,432,-1120,-1568,272,432,64,192,256]'
>>> lst = re.findall(b'\-?\d+', s2)
>>> if lst:
    list_of_integers.extend(lst)


>>> list_of_integers
[b'384', b'-368', b'-304', b'-96', b'0', b'-112', b'-352', b'256', b'304', b'640', b'60', b'432', b'-1120', b'-1568', b'272', b'432', b'64', b'192', b'256']
>>> 
>>> s3 = b'None'
>>> lst = re.findall(b'\-?\d+', s3)
>>> if lst:
        list_of_integers.extend(lst)


>>> list_of_integers
[b'384', b'-368', b'-304', b'-96', b'0', b'-112', b'-352', b'256', b'304', b'640', b'60', b'432', b'-1120', b'-1568', b'272', b'432', b'64', b'192', b'256']
```

Comment: Alright, but what if for ex. *x* gets split up into 2 strings? Now I have a second list, that doesn't have any notation of where it's supposed to go and I don't know whether to append it to *x* or to *y*. My question is about how to convert TWO separate strings into a single list.

Comment: @Janekmuric...in that case, create a general list to hold all captured integers from `lst`, by using the `extend` method as shown in my updated code